# "AttributeError: 'spwd.struct_spwd' object has no attribute 'sp_salt' when authenticating user password in Python"

Tags: python, linux, module, passwords

I'm working on a project where I need to authenticate user passwords that are stored in the shadow file on a Linux system. I'm using the spwd module in Python to access the shadow file, but I'm running into an AttributeError when trying to get the salt for the hashed password.

Here's the code I'm using:

When I run this code with username='root' and password='password', I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'spwd.struct_spwd' object has no attribute 'sp_salt'. Did you mean: 'sp_inact'?


import pwd
import spwd
import crypt
def authenticate_user(username, password):
    try:
        passwd_entry = pwd.getpwnam(username)
        shadow_entry = spwd.getspnam(username)
        hashed_pw = shadow_entry.sp_pwdp
        salt = hashed_pw.split('$')[2]
        return crypt.crypt(password, f'$6${salt}$') == hashed_pw
    except KeyError:
        return False
```